# Can i use something similar on the switch with node.js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, switch-statement

Can i use something similar on the switch with node.js?

```
let = "aggsfg";
if (s[0] == "a" || s[0] == "e" || s[0] == "i" || s[0] == "o" || s[0] == "u") {
    console.log("vogais");
} else if (s[0] == "b" || s[0] == "c" || s[0] == "d" || s[0] == "f" || s[0] == "g") {
    console.log("consoantes1");
}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far? - What are you trying to do?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 3):

```js
let s = "aggsfg";

if ('aeiou'.includes(s[0].toLowerCase())) {
  console.log("vogais");
} else if ('bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz'.includes(s[0].toLowerCase())) {
  console.log("consoantes1");
}
```

You had an error when declaring the variable s.

Comment: @Teemu Fixed. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Node does have a switch statement. See [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_switch.asp).

Answer (score 1):

You can still compress your code using `if` and `includes`. But this is how you can do it with `switch`

```js
let s = "aggsfg";

switch(s[0]) {
  case "a" || "e" || "i" || "o" || "u":
    console.log("vogais")
  case "b" || "c" || "d" || "f" || "g":
    console.log("consoantes1")
}
```